# Is there any way of including C++ commands in a C# program?

Tags: c#, c++

I am very familiar with C and C++, but I am new to C#. Is there any way of including C++ commands in a C# program? For example:

```
cout << "Hello world" ;
```

I realize that C# is a visual language, but it seems like such commands as

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

is awkward if you just want to send something to the screen.

This example is only one example. I am not trying to say that one language is better than the other, but in some cases within a single program to use a command native to C++ than one than one from C#.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to learn idiomatic C#.

Comment: Maybe you should continue to program in C++?

Comment: .. and then compile the c++ code and add it to the c# project :)

Comment: Technically you could use C++/CLI (if you're on Windows with Visual Studio). But you have to already be pretty good with both C++ and .NET to use it properly. And you can't write C# in it.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm

Comment: You think `Console.WriteLine("Hello world");` is awkward and yet you say you're very familiar with C which has the exact same syntax `printf("Hello world");` ?!?!?

Comment: What exactly do you find awkward? The length of `Console.WriteLine` or the syntax function call syntax `F()`?

Comment: The really is no such thing as a 'visual language'.

Comment: @TaW I'd call [this](https://scratch.mit.edu) a 'visual language'.

Comment: Right. I meant of course that the 'Visual' in VS in no way means  that C# or VB  are in any way more 'visual' than c++..

Comment: Also, my view is that it is worth noting that one of the guidelines for posting here is that you need to be happy for other people to edit your posts. Whilst you're welcome to rollback or edit things where the substantive meaning of your post has been incorrectly changed, it is also worth considering keeping changes from experienced users whilst you're learning the ropes. We do prefer succinct posts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use C++s standard library in C#.

What you can do, however, is use C#s standard library (.NET) in C++.

Another option would be to write critical modules in C++ and link with them from C#.

Answer (score 0):

These are not commands these are statements from two different programming languages for doing same thing. Since C# statements is Idiomatic it tries to mimic natural language as much as it can.

But if your goal is to simplify console statement you can do the following. 'using static' will make it more cleaner

```
using static System.Console;
namespace Sample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Write("Some text");
        }
    }
}
```